# Pygame: pygame.time.Clock, or time.sleep

Tags: pygame, pygame-clock

I have a partner in this Pygame project. So it's for fun, and it's Snake.
He says to use `time.sleep` instead of `pygame.clock` since it is 'better'. Is his choice better, or is mine better?

Comment: what do you mean by 'its not better', the clock, or time.sleep, or can you suggest a better one then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) to control the frames per second and thus the game speed.

The method [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object, delays the game in that way, that every iteration of the loop consumes the same period of time. See [`pygame.time.Clock.tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick):

> This method should be called once per frame.

That means that the loop:

> ```py
> clock = pygame.time.Clock()
> run = True
> while run:
>    clock.tick(60)
> ```

runs 60 times per second.

For comparison, `time.sleep` just waits a constant amount of time. If you want to get a constant frame rate you need to use  `pygame.time.Clock.tick`.